# Oracle small blob vs large blob

Tags: oracle, blob

I would like to know what is better way of handling large files such as 3-4 gigabytes as Oracle blob  SecureFile.

The scenario here is, I am planning to upload large files to oracle db over wcf service. I am spiltting file in to smaller chunks of 200mb and uploading it one by one. On oracle side, I just append to the single blob until whole files get uploaded. This happens in sequential manner. However, I am thinking to upload chunks in parallel so I can speed up the operation of uploading. But this will not possible to handle at Oracle end as I can't update single blob with multiple uploads as it would then write bytes not in the order it receives from the service. Is it good than to insert each blob separately and merge them later once into a single blob record in Oracle side?

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Write each chunk to a separate blob, then use DBMS_LOB.APPEND to reconstruct them in the proper order.